# Uncaught ReferenceError: concprop is not defined

Tags: javascript, codepen, uncaught-reference-error

I made a simple code for understanding code pen.

```
<div>
  <span class='title' > Concrete Properties </SPAN>
</div>
<div>
  <span class='keyword'> m<SUB>c</SUB>  </span>
  <span class='equal'>= </span>
    <INPUT id='mc' type='text' value='2300'/>
  <span class='unit' >kg/m<sup>3</sup>  </span>
</div>
<div>
  <span class='keyword'> f<SUB>ck</SUB> </span>
  <span class='equal'>= </span>
    <INPUT id='fck' value='50'/>
  <SPAN class='unit'>MPa</SPAN>
</div>
<button  onclick = "concprop()" > Click</button>
```

```
concprop() ;
function concprop() {
}
```

but i got "Uncaught ReferenceError: concprop is not defined
at [https://cdpn.io/cpe/boomboom/index.html?key=index.html-2f21023a-9843-ec6c-017e-1780ac97ec0c:94"](https://cdpn.io/cpe/boomboom/index.html?key=index.html-2f21023a-9843-ec6c-017e-1780ac97ec0c:94%22) whenever I click button.

I also tried to use

```
<body onload = 'concprop()'>
```

by searching a similiar question from other's.

but it doesn't work.

Any experts to help me to solve this problem?

I can't figure out how to solve it.

my code is as below

https://codepen.io/woluck/pen/zYboKea

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: It seems to be some kind of parsing error caused by the commented out html underneath the demo.  If you put a `-->` at the very end of the commented html, the error no longer appears.